# How do I set a tag of a fragment without a UI programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tried a number of methods such as:

```
Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.MainFrameLayout,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
    .addToBackStack("YOUR_SOURCE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

and adding description in the layout xml file.

Unfortunately, none of these worked. I am wondering if there is a method which allows me to set a tag for the fragment in the activity class associated with it?

Comment: the tag property is not required, you can just pass null in as the value

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tag like how you are setting it works. You should be able to lookup the fragment by its tag using the following:

```
Fragment fragmentA = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
```